# 80's/90's movie: man and woman driving through a red desert planet

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic, androids

I am trying to identify a sci-fi movie from the 80's or 90's, with the following parameters:

Setting:    Scenes of a red desert planet

Culture:    Either people roam fairly solo and try to acquire resources to survive, or you live in a weird society where if a stranger is captured he needs to play in a game of fight to the death.

Mobility:      One foil character has a giant battle-bot-looking tank as his form of transportation through the desert. Protagonist has a car that has a plastic half bubble on top to look out from.

Robot:      The protagonist runs around in the beginning of the film with a female robot/android whose face is melted off after it has acid touch its face.(This scene happens next to the protagonist's rover)

Love interest:      Somehow protagonist comes across female protagonist in desert. She smells really bad and is hungry. They sleep outside, and he tells her to sleep away from him. He uses a thermal blanket(the first I ever saw in my life). She wakes up next to him, smelling horrible. He bathes her in some water hole they find(as if water were not scarce and they could just waste water.)

Pupa monsters:      Scene where they are in a building and they are trying to get out. They come across a room that is white, in which multiple giant, white, snot, pupa are hanging securely from the ceiling. Through curiosity, they disturb them, and now they have to get out of that room fast.

Boss Antagonist:      Pervert bionic man, that is actually attached to a giant robotic arm, as only form of movement. He is in black and has a pale bald head as his most human looking part.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm almost sure you're after *[Spacehunter: Adventures in the Forbidden Zone](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086346/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_46)*

A bounty hunter lands on an alien planet, trying to track down three Earth women whose ship crashlanded there. He rescues Niki (played by a very young Molly Ringwald), who's been living alone on the planet; and goes looking for the women. They've been captured by Overdog (played by Michael Ironsides), who's some kind of cyborg.

[image: Michael Ironside]

Comment: Great bad movie!

Comment: It's got Michael Ironsides in it. He makes any movie great.

Comment: Excellent job Andrewsi. Thanks for helping me find this action filled peculiar movie. I had been Google searching aspects of the movie that I listed above, to no avail-- on and off, for a few months. Andrewsi, I am curious which of the above parameters triggered your mind to reach the target of my search?

Comment: Any movie with Molly Ringwald in it! `</TeenageFantasies>`

Answer (score 0):

It might be [*Fortress* (1992)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortress_(1992_film)), starring Christopher Lambert.

He and his wife get sent to an underground prison because they are having their 2nd baby and in this world women can only have 1 baby due to over population.

The prison is co-run by an AI they eventually escape in a prison truck and have to pull over because his wife is giving birth, they are in the desert.

The AI is able to take control of the truck and Christopher Lambert has to fight it. Hope this helps.

Comment: An answer to this question was accepted in 2014.