# Part-machine scavenger with a red eye trying to save a girl from a tank with spikes and saws

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm trying to figure out the name of a movie.

The protagonist is a scavenger or something similar. He is forced to help save a girl from this cyborg guy who has a red eye, whose body is mostly machine; his arms are like tubes. The protagonist drives this huge metal tank. As he is trying to save this girl, he has to avoid being killed by another tank that has a huge spike roller on it and saws. I think they were in the desert or on Mars. It was a live action movie, I would say mid budget to low, from the 80s or 90s.

Comment: The evil guy was the half human and cyborg. When I watched it I was a kid. I thought it was kevin costner but it isnt.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliminators is one of the more well-known cases of a guy with tank legs. His arms are indeed like tubes and he has a red eye. But most of the movie is in a jungle.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like it's [Spacehunter: Adventures in the Forbidden Zone](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086346/).

The hero is called in to rescue three women who ejected from a starship that was about to be destroyed. They ended up on a barren planet, and have been captured by the villain - our hero must rescue them from his lair. Along the way, he meets up with a young woman (played by Molly Ringwald) who both helps and hinders his plans.

The villain (played by the great Michael Ironside) is a cyborg: [image: Michael Ironside, as entertaining as always]

There are a few vehicles, too; the hero leaves the ship in this one [image: a Scrambler]

In the final act, the hero has been captured by the Overdog, and has to find his way through a maze filled with nasty traps; and one of those does resemble a tank with a giant spiked roller on the front. You can see a brief view of it around the 38 second mark in the trailer.

Trailer:

Comment: For future seachers: see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55606/80s-90s-movie-man-and-woman-driving-through-a-red-desert-planet for additional details on this movie.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly a bit of a long shot, but [Eliminators](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091003/) features a cyborg with tank legs, tubular arms, and a red eye. However, the movie is set in a jungle and the details of being a scavenger, and even of finding and saving a girl don't match.

**Trailer**:

Comment: Ty guys so much this is the movie...

Comment: Wait, Eliminators? Or Spacehunter? Which ever one, you should see a checkmark that you can click on to accept the answer.