# Movie about a sandy planet

Tags: story-identification, movie

The title I'm looking is for a movie from the 70's or 80's about one man in a planet with sand driving a truck and a woman who asks for a lift to go to her father's home, which is under the sand. The home is in a location such that they have to move a car down a ramp, while holding it with a rope. Sorry, but that is what I remember from this movie.

Comment: What makes you think it's a sandy planet, and not just a post apocalyptic Earth or something?

Comment: It sounds like you are roughly describing Cherry 2000. They show a similar scene in the trailer. http://youtu.be/kckEEQKXaCU

Comment: Both of you are right. Looks like I mix two movies. The one with car down the ramp is Cherry 200. Thank you very much. I was for a lot of time looking for that.

Comment: Now, the comment about a man driving a big truck in a sandy planet and a woman asking for a lift and he say no but later he allow her to jump in the truck, is another movie that some one can help me with. This is a marvelous place and I hope may help some one some time. Tony

Comment: see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55606/80s-90s-movie-man-and-woman-driving-through-a-red-desert-planet for more on "Spacehunter: Adventures in the Forbidden Zone"

Comment: see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/196827/80s-sci-fi-film-with-quest-to-replace-lost-female-droid-companion for more on "Cherry 2000"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, as people have commented, that you may be mixing two different films. The bit about the ramp is probably from [Cherry 2000](http://youtu.be/kckEEQKXaCU), but the rest of it doesn't quite fit. I suspect you may also be looking for "Spacehunter : Adventures in the Forbidden Zone", which was a 1983 movie with Molly Ringwald and Peter Strauss [heres the Wikipedia link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacehunter:_Adventures_in_the_Forbidden_Zone)

From the article :

> Wolff continues on alone, but soon catches a teenage Scav named Niki (Molly Ringwald) trying to steal his Scrambler. She convinces Wolff that he needs a tracker if he is to survive The Zone and Wolff reluctantly takes her lead.

The planet they are on is sandy desert and the "Scrambler" is a 4 WD / multi-terrain vehicle.

Comment: Do you want to add the information from the comments above that the bit with the ramp is likely from *Cherry 2000*?

Comment: You are completely right. I'm amazed that how fast and accurate you solve something that was bothering me for years.  Don't know how to rate all of you but five stars and many thanks. Tony