# Mad Max-type Sci-fi movie from the mid-80's with fat blob men

Tags: story-identification, movie

For many years I've been trying to ID a mid-80's cult sci-film that I saw as a kid on TV in the UK. It must have been aired around the late 80's.

My recollection is sketchy but it had a Mad-Max setting, (dusty/rocky landscape) and featured a man with a armoured car. His pal, a black guy, had a larger rig that he drove around in. They both wore light body armour.

The scene I remember was when he tried to escape from a horde of pale, bloated, obese men/creatures who jumped through large tubes and ended up in a small underground bunker.
Yep, sounds weird and it is.

Comment: [Battletruck](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0fl9FqTlvA)?

Comment: [Warrior of the Lost World](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sR_PeHh9wZQ)?

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Good question, I hope someone finds you the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55606/80s-90s-movie-man-and-woman-driving-through-a-red-desert-planet

Comment: May be [The New Barbarians](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lF1vvUDo_EE)? It lacks the pale bloated guys IIRC, but the rest sounds spot on.

Answer (score 15):

This is [Spacehunter: Adventures in the Forbidden Zone](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086346/)

It's very Mad Maxy, with post-apocalypse-standard vehicles etc. All the other points you mention match.

Did the babies look like this?

[image]