# 80s Mad Max-esque space movie with really long name

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

One night when I was a kid, in the mid eighties, I saw a Sci-Fi movie late night on TV. I seem to remember it had a really long name. It opened with the main character on his spaceship (which was kind of a piece of junk), drunk, and talking to his lawyer over radio about his divorce from his wife.

Later, planetside, there were lots of Mad Max-esque vehicles in the desert, some of them really big and complicated. That's about all I remember!

Comment: This could be Spacehunter, which would make it a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131192/mad-max-type-sci-fi-movie-from-the-mid-80s-with-fat-blob-men/131197#131197 and a few others.

Comment: To add to @moopet's comment, Spacehunter has the subtitle "Adventures in the Forbidden Zone", and in some versions, adds "in 3-D" though that version was probably limited to theatres. In any case, that would account for your memory of it having a long name.

Comment: While everything else from Spacehunter: Adventures in the Forbidden Zone does match, I dont remember him "talking to his lawyer over radio about his divorce from his wife." But it has been a long time and I may be miss remembering it.

Comment: @NJohnny OP is talking about the opening scene where the main character is receiving a backlog of messages over the radio - the person reading the messages mentions that there's one from the main character's ex-wife complaining that she hasn't received a cheque in six months - but it's never suggested that the person reading the messages is the main character's lawyer.

Comment: @TheBeardyMan It was a long time ago - about 35 years! - so I have probably misremembered, but that sounds very promising, thanks!

Comment: @TheBeardyMan Ok that sounds better. It was probably "Chamers" the female robot who was reading the messages after fixing the comms. I am sure this is the correct movie now. :)

Comment: @drkvogel - Are any of the answers currently posted correct? If so, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Or if none of them are correct, please leave a comment confirming that, so we know to keep looking. Thanks.

Comment: One of the two films in the answers was shown in 3D, with a very jarring shot at one point where the frames were tilted (to make a slope appear steeper when a vehicle was on it) but the stereo not corrected.  I saw both in theaters, as well as *Ice Pirates* which was in a similar vein but lacked the long title.

Answer (score 7):

Vanguard3000 and moopet suggest [*Spacehunter: Adventures in the Forbidden Zone*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086346/) (1983).
I note that teenage Molly Ringwald was an important character in [Spacehunter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacehunter:_Adventures_in_the_Forbidden_Zone) (1983).

*Spacehunter: Adventures in the Forbidden Zone* (1983) is a possibility.

Comment: Spacehunter, as I remember it, definitely matches some of the OPs description. I remember it starting out on a junky old space ship, and much of the rest was on a planet.

Comment: I saw Spacehunter, and I don't remember the hero talking to a lawyer or having a wife- I do recall a woman-android partner that broke down early on.

Answer (score 3):

[*Metalstorm: The Destruction of Jared-Syn*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085935/) (1983) was from the early 1980s and had a long title.

I note that the very tall Richard Moll of *Night Court* appeared in [*Metalstorm: The Destruction of Jared-Syn*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalstorm:_The_Destruction_of_Jared-Syn) (1983).

Thus *Metalstorm: The Destruction of Jared-Syn* (1983) might possibly be the remembered movie.

### Trailer